# How to split sentences into correlated words (term extraction)?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, text-extraction

Is there any NLP python library that split sentence or joins words into related pairs of words? For example:

> That is not bad example -> "That" "is" "not bad" "example"

"Not bad" means the same as good so it would be useless to process it as "not" and "bad" in machine learning.
I dont even know how to call these pairs of words that are correlated. (term extraction? phases extraction?)
Or would be even better to split into adjectives with nouns for example:

> dishonest media relating about tax cuts -> "dishonest media", "relating", "about", "tax cuts"

I found topia.termextract but it does not work with python3.

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html part 2.1

Comment: checkout spacy.  https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-tokenization I don't know why people downvoted.

Comment: where does it say in docs how to do that? I can't see it

Comment: see the section on `PhraseMatcher()` in "Rules-based Matching". It is a highly customizable framework that allows for lemma rules, regex, etc. But isn't an out of the box solution. Anyway. Cheers

Comment: 'not bad' is not the same as 'good'... in fact it's less than good but higher than bad.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Spacy library](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#rule-based-matching) (see links).

It doesn't have that functionality out of the box, as you need to build the rules, but the rules are very human readable, and there are many options you can feed in (POS tags, regex, lemma, or any combination of those, etc.)

Of particular note are the sections on the `PhraseMarker()` [class](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher).

Directly copied from the documentation is a code sample:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher 
import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load('en')
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
terminology_list = ['Barack Obama', 'Angela Merkel', 'Washington, D.C.']
patterns = [nlp(text) for text in terminology_list]
matcher.add('TerminologyList', None, *patterns)

doc = nlp(u"German Chancellor Angela Merkel and US President Barack Obama "
          u"converse in the Oval Office inside the White House in Washington, D.C.")
matches = matcher(doc)
```

Comment: If it's just a list of pre-known gazetteer, NLTK does that too https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664608/610569 =)

Comment: Totally. But the customization and ease of use have been rather impressive to me. I've used both, but Spacy has some other features that have made me start using it (outside the scope of this question).

Comment: That is not what I want. I want to to match any nouns, not only predefined ones.

Comment: Read the rest of the documentation. It does allow you to automatically pair words based on POS and word dependencies.

Comment: Specifically, Spacy says `The rule matcher (class) also lets you pass in a custom callback to act on matches – for example, to merge entities and apply custom labels.` Those custom labels would be your new tokenization scheme. You could also leverage the dependency parsing section of the documentation. (https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-dependency-parse). The tools are all there but you aren't going to find a plug-n-play solution for what you are asking for; Whether you would want to group "tax cuts" and/or "dishonest media" is highly use case dependent.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically detect common phrases from a stream of sentences I recommend you to check [Gensim Phrase (collocation) detection](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html)

Good example of how it works:

> bigram = Phraser(phrases)
>
> sent = [u'the', u'mayor', u'of', **u'new', u'york'**, u'was', u'there']
>
> print(bigram[sent])
>
> Output: [u'the', u'mayor', u'of', **u'new_york'**, u'was', u'there']

Comment: OP wants to pair up not noun chunks, (which gensim does quite well), but dependency parsing of words closely linked together.There are methods to do this in both NLTK and some other tokenization libraries, but OP seems to want something out of the box

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ML model you use and how it has been trained.
The standard would be nltk or textblob

textblob I believe should already be trained up for these language nuisances:

```
import re
x = ' '.join(re.sub('(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)', ' ', 'That is not bad example').split())

from textblob import TextBlob
analysis = TextBlob(x)
sentiment = analysis.sentiment.polarity
```

the above code should yield the following sentiments:

```
'That is bad example' : -0.6999999999999998    
'That is not bad example' : 0.3499999999999999
'That is good example' : 0.7
'That is not good example' : -0.35
```

already you can see that this sentiment analyzer has grasped some concept of double negative and negative positive. It can be trained further by invoking:

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(training_Set)
```

and using `cl`but effort would be better spent by you defining what is a positive sentiment by some arbitrary threshold (if > 0.1 then good). I mean the 'bad' and 'not good' are already negative... so why try to re-invent the wheel?

ML right now is "smart enough"... you often have to use your own intelligence to bridge the gap that the machine lacks...

you can also use `sentiment = analysis.sentiment.subjectivity` to see how objective or subjective the text is to offer you more insight