# Tokenize multi word in python

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I'm new in python . I have a big data set from twitter and i want to tokenize it .
but i don't know how can i token verbs like this : "look for , take off ,grow up and etc." and it's important to me .
my code is :

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> s = "I'm looking for the answer"
>>> word_tokenize(s)
['I', "'m", 'looking', 'for', 'the', 'answer']
```

my data set is big and i can't use this page code :
[Find multi-word terms in a tokenized text in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663870/find-multi-word-terms-in-a-tokenized-text-in-python)

so , how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parts of speech` tags for that, or actually `dependency parsing` would be more accurate. I haven't tried with nltk, but with spaCy you can do it like this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
def chunk_phrasal_verbs(lemmatized_sentence):

    ph_verbs = []
    for word in nlp(lemmatized_sentence):
        if word.dep_ == 'prep' and word.head.pos_ == 'VERB':
            ph_verb = word.head.text+ ' ' + word.text
            ph_verbs.append(ph_verb)
    return ph_verbs
```

I also suggest first `lemmatizing` the sentence to get rid of conjugations. Also if you need noun phrases, with the similar way you can use compound relationship.